# TS7016: TypeScript don't see plain .js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I got below error when tried to import some variables from plain `.js` file (`JsModuleForStaticImport.js`). Similar `.ts` loads without error.

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './StaticallyImportedModules/JsModuleForStaticImport'.
```

[image]

I started from the minimal TS config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

The contains of `JsModuleForStaticImport.js`:

```
const CONST_THAT_IMPORTED_BY_DEFAULT_FROM_STATIC_JS_MODULE =
   'I am const that imported by default from status JS module.';
export default CONST_THAT_IMPORTED_BY_DEFAULT_FROM_STATIC_JS_MODULE;

export const CONST_THAT_IMPORTED_FROM_STATIC_JS_MODULE =
   'I am const that imported (no by default) from status JS module.';
```

Of course, `resolve.extensions` from webpack configuration includes both `.ts` and `.js`.

```
module.exports = [
  { 

    // ...

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  }
]
```

What lucks my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the `allowJs` compiler option:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": "true",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "strict": true
  }
}
```